# How to change sharing permission google drive subfolder files?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a main folder `Folder 1`
inside `Folder 1` there is multiple subfolder which have files. i want to change all subfolder files sharing permission `Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK` no sign in require. currently i have follow code but it only work if there is no subfolders.

```
    function myFunction() {
      var folderId = "Folder ID";
      var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
      var result = [];
      while (files.hasNext()) {
          var file = files.next();
          file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
          var temp = {
            file_name: file.getName(),
            url: "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + file.getId(),
          };
          result.push(temp);
      };

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you with your current problem:

```
 function myFunction() {
   var folderId = "main-id-folder";
   // Take the mainder folder
   var mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
   // Take the subfolders inside your main folder
   var subFolders = mainFolder.getFolders();
   var result = [];
   
   // Iterate over each subfolder
   while(subFolders.hasNext()){
     var subFolder = subFolders.next();
     // Take the files inside the current subfolder
     var files = subFolder.getFiles();
     // Take each file inside the current subfolder
     while(files.hasNext()){
       var file = files.next();
       var tmp = {
         file_name: file.getName(),
         url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + file.getId() + "/edit#gid=0"
       };
       // For the current file, stablish the permissions you want
       file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
       result.push(tmp);
     }
   }
   Logger.log(result);
}
```

The problem you had is you were only trying to get the files from your main folder but in order to get the files inside each subfolder, you needed to first take each subfolder using  `.getFolders();` and then for each one of them, you could use `.getFiles();`.

### Docs

These are the docs I used to help you, in case you want to see them or anyone else who has a similar issue:

- [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html#top_of_page)
- [Enum Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access.html)